# Adding a conditioned return in a Scope (be able to chain scopes in a scope depending on conditions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a recurrent code with conditions in a new permission recently added code. It was not designed from the start, so it is a little messy:

```
@usuarios = Usuario.menores_de_edad.con_autorizacion(params[:autorizacion]).con_nombre(params[:nombre])
# master puede ver todos, así que ignora los permisos
if !usuario_actual.es_master?
  if usuario_actual.permiso.blank?
    # Si es admin y no tiene permisos establecidos
    @usuarios = Usuario.where(id: nil)
  else
    # Lee de que niveles puedes mostrar los usuarios
    @usuarios = @usuarios.del_nivel(usuario_actual.permiso.niveles)
  end
end
if usuario_actual.es_admin_occ?
  @usuarios = @usuarios.de_occ
end
```

I want to make it a scope this way:

```
@usuarios = Usuario.menores_de_edad.con_autorizacion(params[:autorizacion]).con_nombre(params[:nombre])
@usuarios = @usuarios.permitibles(usuario_actual)
```

How can I make it work? I have currently this:

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :permitibles, lambda{ |usuario_actual|
    # master can see everything, so, don't scope anything at all
    if !usuario_actual.es_master?
      if usuario_actual.permiso.blank?
        # return nothing if you don't have permissions
        where(id: nil)
      else
        # this is a scope
        del_nivel(usuario_actual.permiso.niveles)
      end

      if usuario_actual.es_admin_occ?
        # this is a scope
        de_occ
      end
    end
  }
end
```

The problem is, inside the scope, that I don't know how to chain the other scopes, I mean, "de_occ" must be chained depending on the other condition, but right now this will will not work as is, because it will return only one scope instead of chaining "de_occ" to the first condition. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's little problematic for me to go through your code. The best practice is not to use you mother langauge as a source of model and method names.

The basic approach for your problem would be to move the logic into a method and chains scopes / sqls. Here is a proof of concept:

```
scope :menores_de_edad, ->() {where(something: true)}
scope :del_nivel, ->(params) {where(field: param)}
scope :de_occ, ->() { ... }


def self.we_are_chaining_scopes
   result = self.scoped

   if !usuario_actual.es_master?
      if usuario_actual.permiso.blank?
        # return nothing if you don't have permissions
        result = result.menores_de_edad 
      else
        # this is a scope
         result = result.del_nivel(usuario_actual.permiso.niveles)
      end

      if usuario_actual.es_admin_occ?
        # this is a scope
        result = result.de_occ
      end

    end

   result
end
```

You can make it even nicer by creating **a service object** for this query. Rough example:

```
class SpecificQuery
  def initialize(relation = Model.scoped)
    @relation = relation
  end

 private

  def scoped_to(&block)
    @relation = @relation.instance_eval(&block)
  end

 def scoped_behavior_method_one(param)
    scoped_to { where(:something: param) }
  end

 def scoped_behavior_method_two(param)
    scoped_to { ... }
  end
end
```

And then you can chain scopes nicely as well + you're encapsulating the logic which should not necessarily belongs to your model. Also, it's easier to write specs :) I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!, the missing part for me it was "self.scoped", you are absolutely right about asking with code in my mother language, will take this in consideration for further questions.
And I don't know anything about service objects, will try to follow your example and search more about it to leave my models more small. Great answer!